# Populating jQuery accordion with Handlebars with nested div

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, accordion

I have built an accordion with jQuery and populated the contents via a handlebars template and it works as expected.  However when I expand the solution to include a nested div within the body only the nested content of the first accordion row functions.  The other accordion rows will expand and show the upper level details, but the embedded div does not populate.

I have populated the nested div with both static content and with data from the handlebars template but the results are the same.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Active Client List</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //toggle the component with class clientbody
            $(".clienthead").click(function () {
                if ($('.clientbody').is(':visible')) {
                    $(".clientbody").slideUp(330);
                    $(".plusminus").text('+');
                }
                if ($(this).next(".clientbody").is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).next(".clientbody").slideUp(400);
                    $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).next(".clientbody").slideDown(330);
                    $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
                }
            });
            $('#appointcontainer').click(function () {
                $('#appointlst').slideToggle(400);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/clientlst.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Active Client List</h3>
    <div id="clientcontainer">
        <!-- clientListTemplate Handlebar template start -->
        <script id='clientListTemplate' type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#each clients}}
            <div id="clienthead" class="clienthead">
                {{name}}
                <span></span>
                <span class="plusminus">+</span>

            </div>
            <div id="clientbody" class="clientbody " style="display: none;">
                <table class="clientdet">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdicon"><img src="icons/phone.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" /></td>
                        <td style="width:200px"> - {{fone}}</td>
                        <td rowspan="2" align="right"><img src="{{avitar}}" style="height:60px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdicon"><img src="icons/mail.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" /></td>
                        <td> - {{email}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <!--  partial template content begin -->
                            <div id="appointlst">
                                <hr />
                                <p>Appointment 1</p>
                                <p>Appointment 2</p>
                                <p>Appointment 3</p>
                            </div>
                            <!--  partial template content end -->
                            <!-- div function as button for slidetoggle begin -->
                            <div id="appointcontainer">
                                <img id="calmonth" src="icons/calmonth.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" />
                                <span class="appointcontainer"> - Appointments</span>
                                <img id="downApp" src="icons/down.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" />
                            </div>
                            <!-- div function as button for slidetoggle end -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </script>
        <!-- clientListTemplate Handlebar template end -->
    </div>
    <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.11.js"></script>
    <script src="js/clientlst.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The js file is quite simple:

```
var clntRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
clntRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost/trainer/json/clientlst.json');
clntRequest.onload = function () {
    if (clntRequest.status >= 200 && clntRequest.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(clntRequest.responseText);
        createHTML(data);
    } else {
        console.log('Connect active, error returned');
    }
};

clntRequest.onerror = function () {
    console.log('Connection error');
};

clntRequest.send();

function createHTML(clientdata) {
    var rawTemplate = document.getElementById('clientListTemplate').innerHTML;
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
    var generatedHTML = compiledTemplate(clientdata);
    var accordioncontainer = document.getElementById('clientcontainer');
    accordioncontainer.innerHTML = generatedHTML;
}
```

The json file I am using for this prototype is as follows:

```
{
  "clients":  [
    {
      "name": "Abbot, Jerome",
      "fone": "(770) 233-0025",
      "email": "abbotj@aol.com",
      "avitar": "icons/abelincoln.jpg",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "sdate": "March 31, 2018",
          "timeframe": "1",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Piedmont Park"
        },
        {
          "sdate": "February 26, 2018",
          "timeframe": "0",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Decatur"
        },
        {
          "sdate": "February 16, 2018",
          "timeframe": "0",
          "starttime": "08:30",
          "endtime": "09:30",
          "location": "Piedmont Park"
        }
      ] 
    },
    {
      "name": "Alexander, Jason",
      "fone": "(404) 237-1138",
      "email": "jalexander@aol.com",
      "avitar": "icons/gandhi.jpg",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "sdate": "March 27, 2018",
          "timeframe": "1",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Buckhead"
        },
        {
          "sdate": "March 06, 2018",
          "timeframe": "0",
          "starttime": "08:30",
          "endtime": "09:30",
          "location": "Buckhead"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Bobber, Harriott",
      "fone": "(678) 313-7272",
      "email": "harriott.bobber4j@gmail.com",
      "avitar": "icons/user.png",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "sdate": "April 04, 2018",
          "timeframe": "1",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Piedmont Park"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also enclosed the css:

```
body{background-color: navajowhite;}
#clientcontainer {width: 320px;}
#clienthead {
    background-color: #847c7c;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 7px 11px 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#clientbody {background: transparent;padding-left: 15px;}
.clientdet {background-color:transparent;}
#tdicon {vertical-align:bottom;width:27px;}
.sched_link{font-size:smaller;font-weight:lighter;}
.plusminus {float: right;}
.links {float: left;display: inline-block;width: 200px;}
.avitar {float: right;display: inline-block;width: 100px;}
#appointcontainer {border-bottom: 4px solid, red;}
#calmonth {vertical-align: middle;}
#appointlst {display: none;}
#downApp {float: right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work, you can run the below snippet to see, I've just copy paste your code in the snippet (and tuned a bit in order to have handlebar result content inserted). Have you checked in the DOM that your code is not rendered or have you just seen on screen that your data isn't present ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = {
  "clients":  [
    {
      "name": "Abbot, Jerome",
      "fone": "(770) 233-0025",
      "email": "abbotj@aol.com",
      "avitar": "icons/abelincoln.jpg",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "sdate": "March 31, 2018",
          "timeframe": "1",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Piedmont Park"
        },
        {
          "sdate": "February 26, 2018",
          "timeframe": "0",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Decatur"
        },
        {
          "sdate": "February 16, 2018",
          "timeframe": "0",
          "starttime": "08:30",
          "endtime": "09:30",
          "location": "Piedmont Park"
        }
      ] 
    },
    {
      "name": "Alexander, Jason",
      "fone": "(404) 237-1138",
      "email": "jalexander@aol.com",
      "avitar": "icons/gandhi.jpg",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "sdate": "March 27, 2018",
          "timeframe": "1",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Buckhead"
        },
        {
          "sdate": "March 06, 2018",
          "timeframe": "0",
          "starttime": "08:30",
          "endtime": "09:30",
          "location": "Buckhead"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Bobber, Harriott",
      "fone": "(678) 313-7272",
      "email": "harriott.bobber4j@gmail.com",
      "avitar": "icons/user.png",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "sdate": "April 04, 2018",
          "timeframe": "1",
          "starttime": "09:00",
          "endtime": "10:00",
          "location": "Piedmont Park"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
  Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEqualsChained', function() {
      var options = arguments[arguments.length-1];
      // Assuming that all wanted operator are '||'
      valueToTest=arguments[0];
      for (var i = 1; i < (arguments.length - 1); i++) {
        if (valueToTest === arguments[i]) {
          return options.fn(this);
        }
      }
      return options.inverse(this);
  });
  var source = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
              $(".clienthead").click(function () {
                if ($('.clientbody').is(':visible')) {
                    $(".clientbody").slideUp(330);
                    $(".plusminus").text('+');
                }
                if ($(this).next(".clientbody").is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).next(".clientbody").slideUp(400);
                    $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).next(".clientbody").slideDown(330);
                    $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
                }
            });
            $('#appointcontainer').click(function () {
                $('#appointlst').slideToggle(400);
            });

});
```

```css
body{background-color: navajowhite;}
#clientcontainer {width: 320px;}
#clienthead {
    background-color: #847c7c;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 7px 11px 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#clientbody {background: transparent;padding-left: 15px;}
.clientdet {background-color:transparent;}
#tdicon {vertical-align:bottom;width:27px;}
.sched_link{font-size:smaller;font-weight:lighter;}
.plusminus {float: right;}
.links {float: left;display: inline-block;width: 200px;}
.avitar {float: right;display: inline-block;width: 100px;}
#appointcontainer {border-bottom: 4px solid, red;}
#calmonth {vertical-align: middle;}
#appointlst {display: none;}
#downApp {float: right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     {{#each clients}}
            <div id="clienthead" class="clienthead">
                {{name}}
                <span></span>
                <span class="plusminus">+</span>

            </div>
            <div id="clientbody" class="clientbody " style="display: none;">
                <table class="clientdet">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdicon"><img src="icons/phone.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" /></td>
                        <td style="width:200px"> - {{fone}}</td>
                        <td rowspan="2" align="right"><img src="{{avitar}}" style="height:60px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdicon"><img src="icons/mail.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" /></td>
                        <td> - {{email}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <!--  partial template content begin -->
                            <div id="appointlst">
                                <hr />
                                <p>Appointment 1</p>
                                <p>Appointment 2</p>
                                <p>Appointment 3</p>
                            </div>
                            <!--  partial template content end -->
                            <!-- div function as button for slidetoggle begin -->
                            <div id="appointcontainer">
                                <img id="calmonth" src="icons/calmonth.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" />
                                <span class="appointcontainer"> - Appointments</span>
                                <img id="downApp" src="icons/down.png" style="height:22px;width:22px;" />
                            </div>
                            <!-- div function as button for slidetoggle end -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
</script>
 <h3>Active Client List</h3>
    <div id="clientcontainer">
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
</div>
```